# How can I hide related products when a user is not logged in?

Tags: magento2, plugin

We need to hide related products when a user is not logged in. I can make this work by overriding the /Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml template and putting the conditional code in there. However, this seems like it isn't the best solution because I would need to integrate changes from future Magento upgrades into that overridden template.

I'm trying to use a plugin to override the template in the case that the user is not logged in. I have a custom module working correctly.

In MyCompany\MyModule\etc.di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related">
        <plugin name="rb-hidepricing-relatedproducts-plugin" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Related" />
    </type>
</config>
```

In MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Related.php

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

/**
 * Class Related
 *
 * @package MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList
 */
class Related
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $subject)
    {
        $isLoggedin = $subject->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink')->isLoggedIn();
        if (!$isLoggedIn) {
            $subject->setTemplate('MyCompany_MyModule::product/hide_related.phtml');
        }
    }


}
```

And in MyCompany\MyModule\view\frontend\templates\product\hide_related.phtml

```
Login to see related products.
```

When I load the product page now I see the related products regardless if the user is logged in. I use this check for $isLoggedIn in other places successfully. I have cleared cache. I took out the conditional and just set the template, it still shows related products.

I suspect I am missing something basic - this is my first time using a plugin.

UPDATE: Looking in generated directory I find an Interceptor for the class I am trying to add a plugin for, with a method for toHtml that calls plugins. Apparently the di.xml is having an effect, even though the plugin itself doesn't seem to be running. I am in developer mode, and I see some other questions here about plugins not being generated in developer mode.